# State space model affected from future events?

Tags: time-series, bayesian, state-space-models

I understand that a state-space model is a common model where the current observation $y_t$ depends on the current state $x_t$.

Is there any common model where the current observation $y_t$ depends on the future states $x_{t+1}, x_{t+2}, x_{t+3},...$? I'd like to know a popular model representing future states' effects, and also inference method of its parameters.

I think it's common phenomenon where the current observation depends on the future ones.

For example, someone might need to leave home for her office earlier than usual because she has an appointment with a customer in that morning. The future event, which is the appointment, has a effect to the current observation, which is her behavior. Likewise, stock price also depends on the future event like next IR announcement and business statistics.

I searched on google scholar with "time series future event", and get to know [Trend Impact Analysis](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040162509000055). However, it does not look employing formal statistics model like state space model.

The following image is a graphical representation of a state-space model and the model in my question.

[image]

### Update (9:21AM Feb 14 2016)

In my understanding of @ZacharyBlumenfeld's comment,  my problem can be represented as the following graphical model. I think this model is similar to Figure (b).

**How do I predict future value $y_{t+i}$ on this model?**

[image]

In Figure (c), $x_t^{(i)}$ denotes the belief of $x_{t+i}$ at $t$.

Comment: There's a large field (and has been for many decades) called Dynamic Programming.  You might see things listed as "Stochastic Dynamic Programming" or "Dynamic Programming and Stochastic Control", in which probability distributions for future states as a function of current actions (control) are used as the basis for determining the optimal action at a given time given the current state.  See for example, http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-231-dynamic-programming-and-stochastic-control-fall-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_231F11_notes_2011.pdf .

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I think on stochastic dynamic programming, current auction affect the future state. How come dynamic programming is equivalent to my model shown in fig (b)?

Comment: There are instances where we know (with nearly 100% certainty) that a certain event will happen in the future and this knowledge effects the dynamics of our response.  i.e. knowing that the Fed will increase interests rates in the future will effect the bond market today.  but in this setting, if at time $t$ the fed announced that it will raise interest rates $h$ periods in the future, we would denote the event as $x^{(h)}_{t}$ as opposed to $x_{t+h}$.  this would keep the time ordering consistent when we conditioned bond prices on the announcement $y_{t},y_{t+1},.... y_{t+h}| x^{(h)}_t$

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld My understanding is that you suggest that the future state x_{t+h} can be merged into x_t as x_t^h.  Is it always the case? At least, for the past states, I don't think so. If the all past states could be merged into x_t, the n-th Markov model (n>1) would not be necessary. I believe this situation is similar for the future states and some well studied model can exist.

Comment: What I was trying to point out is that you can express *hearing news* about future events in contemporaneous time.  Unless you have a time machine it is really awkward to condition on future events.  In reality we don't really condition on future events anyway but rather on news and predictions about those future events (which are in most realistic circumstances imperfect).  So in a state space model you could express a vector of states of belief $x^{(0)}_t,...,x^{(h)}_t$ which gets *updated* moving forward in time  $x^{(0)}_{t+1},...,x^{(h)}_{t+1}$, s.t. $x^{(2)}_t \neq x^{(1)}_{t+1}$.

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld I guess one of enlightening notions you provided is 'belief'.  Does this graphical model at the link represent what you mentioned correctly? http://imgur.com/a/lDTsz If my understanding is correct, the model is similar to fig (b) and need a method to infer variables.